# Downgoat-ify Animals!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, image-processing

My Downgoat avatar has several distinct features

[image]

These features can however also apply to any other animal.

### Specification

Given an image of an animal (technically can be anything), you must apply the Downgoat properties to it.

**Border pixels** are the outer most pixels of the image.

The **background color** is defined as the most common color in the border pixels. When that color is interpreted as an (r, g, b, a) color, with each channel from [0, 256), the background is defined as the area where the every channel of the given pixels' is within 50 of the "background color".

The process:

- Setting the background and all transparent pixels to `#232323`, `RGBA(35, 35, 35, 1.00)`
- Set all pixels which aren't the background to `#FC0D1B`, `RGBA(252, 13, 27, 1.00)`.
- Vertically reflect the image
- Add the text `-1` in Arial font, in the center of the image. The total height of the text should be 25% of the image's smallest dimension (i.e. `min(width, height) * 0.25`).

### Rules

- Feel free to assume the fonts are already installed
- Your threshold is supposed to be `50`, however you can take this number as input too. You do *not* get any decreased byte count anything for doing this however
- Refer to our [image I/O defaults](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9093/40695) for any questions related to I/O formats.
- Image will always be at least 3x3 in size
- If there is no most common "border pixel color", it doesn't matter which border pixel color you use as the "background color", this however must be consistent.

### Examples

Input: [image: Goat]

Output: [image: Downgoat]

---

Input:
[image: Squid]

Output:
[image: Downsquid]

Input: [image: Downgoat]

Output: [image: Downdowngoat]

---

Input: [image: Dennis]

Output: [image: Downdennis]

---

Input: [image: Trichoplax]

Output: [image: Downtrichoplax]

---

**More examples?**

An online implementation is available here: [vihan.org/p/downgoatify/#50](http://vihan.org/p/downgoatify#50)

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins. Good luck!

Comment: -1 First test case not an animal -_-

Comment: -1ˢᵗ test case not an animal either.

Comment: @Geobits okay, fine fixed

Comment: Not a fan of demon dennis

Comment: You could eliminate the worry about whether it's an animal by changing "animal" to "avatar" in the title and throughout the question.

Comment: What is the point of enforcing the font to use? The only thing this does is penalize languages where changing font takes more bytes

Comment: @Fatalize because image input can be taken as an array of channels, I want this to be more complex than some basic array transformation and drawing a vertical line in the middle and calling that a one

Comment: @Downgoat You have removed the penguin image. Does this mean that the program does not need to work with image formats having an "alpha" channel?

Comment: The background definition makes this way harder than necessary. You could also have said to provide a B/W image, or transparent/non-transparent. I thought about heading for a CSS3 solution, but like that it's simply impossible.

Comment: I suspect that your example "output" for the dennis-the-menace image was generated from a different (better, without JPEG artifacts) original.  I was not able to avoid getting JPEG artifacts in my result.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson you shouldn't have a problem with the fuzziness if the threshold is implemented correctly. Perhaps check that?

Comment: Well, "fuzz 8%" works better but still not an exact repro of your result.  It appears that in that case my script was using 50/65k rather than 50/255 as the threshold.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## ImageMagick 7.0.3 + bash + sed, 379 bytes

```
M=magick K=\#232323 P='-chop x%[fx:u[0].h-2]-0+1'
$M $1 -depth 8 ppm:W;$M W $P T;$M W -rotate 90 -shave 1x $P L
C=`$M T L +append -statistic mode +0 txt:-|sed -e "1d;s/.*#/#/;s/ .*//;q"`
$M W -background $K -flatten -fill $K -fuzz 20% -opaque $C +fuzz -fill \#FC0D1B +opaque $K -flip -pointsize %[fx:.282*min\(u[0].w,u[0].h\)] -fill white -draw 'gravity center text 0,0 "-1"' x:
```

## Ungolfed

```
# Make aliases for things we'll use repeatedly
M=magick K=\#232323 P='-chop x%[fx:u[0].h-2]-0+1'

# Copy the input file to a PPM file
$M $1 -depth 8 ppm:W

# Extract the border pixels into "T" (top and bottom), and "L" (left and right)
# PPM files, removing the ends from the "L" because they were already counted 
$M W $P T;$M W -rotate 90 -shave 1x $P L

# Put the borders into one strip and reduce to a txt image of the "mode"
# color on stdout, then convert the first pixel to hex format string "C"
C=`$M T L +append -statistic mode +0 txt:-|sed -e "1d;s/.*#/#/;s/ .*//;q"`

# Make background "#232323" and compose transparent pixels against it
# Convert any pixels with color within "fuzz" distance of background to #232323
# Convert any remaining pixels to "#FC0D1B"
# Flip the image vertically
# Determine pointsize for text, 1/5 of min(w,h). 1 pixel == 1.44 points
# Draw text "-1" centered on the image
# Display the result to an X window

$M W -background $K -flatten                     \
-fill $K -fuzz 20% -opaque $C                    \
+fuzz -fill \#FC0D1B +opaque $K                  \
-flip                                            \
-pointsize %[fx:.282*min\(u[0].w,u[0].h\)]       \
-fill white -draw 'gravity center text 0,0 "-1"' \
x:
```

[image: Inputs and Outputs]

I'm getting a quite different answer for the dennis image, probably because ImageMagick's "-fuzz" computes a sphere with diameter of 2N units in rgb coordinates while the rules call for computing a cube with sides of 101 units in rgb coordinates. Varying the "fuzz" helped some.  Also, the JPEG artifacts in the original seem to be interfering with the conversion.

Comment: I'm not familliar with imageMagick, so this may be very uneducated, but can you replace the #0000 color code with simply #0?

Comment: No, #0 doesn't work.  Neither does #000 because that's opaque black and we need transparent black here.

Comment: The bug that I mentioned, `# ImageMagick 7.0.1 through 7.0.3-7 fails here` has been reported to the IM developers and is fixed in version 7.0.3-8.

Answer (score 11):

### C, 32-bit Windows, 987 bytes

```
#include <windows.h>
#define A CreateCompatibleDC(c)
#define F z=GetPixel(d,x,y);r=z;g=z>>8;b=z>>16
#define C(X,Y) (X<0||Y<0||X>=s[2]||Y>=s[3]||!GetPixel(e,X,Y))
#define D ((C(x-1,y)||C(x+1,y)||C(x,y-1)||C(x,y+1))&&!C(x,y))
#define E(X,Y) ((Z+X-Y)*(Z+X-Y)<2501)
main(int a,int*n){HDC c,d,e,f,w;int x,y,s[9],z,*o,m,t,Z;unsigned char r,g,b,R,G,B;c=GetDC(w=GetDesktopWindow());d=A;e=A;SelectObject(d,f=LoadImage(0,n[1],0,0,0,16));SelectObject(e,LoadImage(0,n[2],0,0,0,16));GetObject(f,24,s+1);o=LocalAlloc(64/*Fixed,ZeroInit*/,8*s[2]*s[3]);for(x=t=Z=s[1]=s[0]=0;x<s[2];x++)for(y=0;y<s[3];y++)if D{F;for(m=0;m<t&&o[m]!=z;m+=2);o[m]=z;o[m+1]++;t+=2*(m>=t);}for(x=y=1;x<t;x+=2)if(o[x]>o[y])y=x;z=o[y-1];R=z;G=z>>8;B=z>>16;for(x=0;x<s[2];x++)for(y=0;y<s[3];y++){F;SetPixel(c,x,s[3]-y-1,(C(x,y)||(E(r,R)&&E(g,G)&&E(b,B)))?0x232323:0x1B0DFC);}SelectObject(c,CreateFont(-(s[2]>>2),0,0,0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Arial"));SetBkMode(c,1);SetTextColor(c,0xFFFFFF);DrawText(c,"-1",2,s,37);ReleaseDC(w,c);}
```

- The file is saved with LF as line end, not with CR+LF to save some bytes.
- The program is written in a way that compiler warnings are generated to save some more bytes.
- The file will probably not compile as 64-bit program because the array "`s[]`" is used to do some implicit castings...
- The program takes two images (file names are given via command line):

  - The first image (first command line argument) is the R/G/B image in Windows .BMP format
  - The second image is the Alpha channel (black means: 0%, any other colour means: not 0%); the file is also in .BMP format and must have the same size or be larger than the first image
- The output image is displayed in the left upper corner of the screen
- I couldn't reproduce the boy with the yellow hair. Yellow seems to be too far away (> 50) from white!

Ungolfed version:

```
#include <windows.h>

/*
 * Although this line costs us 32 bytes
 * Replacing "CreateCompatibleDC(c)" we'll
 * save 42 bytes in the golfed version later
 * so we save 10 bytes using this define!
 */
#define A CreateCompatibleDC(c)

/*
 * Macro: Get a pixel value at (x,y) to z
 * Also get r, g, b
 */
#define F z=GetPixel(d,x,y); \
    r=z; \
    g=z>>8; \
    b=z>>16

/*
 * Macro checking if a pixel is a
 * transparent colour or lies outside the
 * image
 */
#define C(X,Y) (X<0 || Y<0 || X>=s[2] || Y>=s[3] || !GetPixel(e,X,Y))

/*
 * Macro checking if a pixel at (x,y) is a border pixel
 */
#define D ((C(x-1,y) || C(x+1,y) || C(x,y-1) || C(x,y+1)) && !C(x,y))

/*
 * Macro checking if the difference between X and Y is less than 50
 * The variable "Z" must be type "int" and zero. It is used to
 * perform an implicit cast from "BYTE" to "int".
 */
#define E(X,Y) ((Z+X-Y)*(Z+X-Y)<2501)

/*
 * Note that the second argument is "char **",
 * not "int *".
 * We ignore resulting compiler warnings...
 */
main(int a, int * n)
{
    HDC c, d, e, f, w;
    int x, y, s[9], z, *o, m, t, Z;
    unsigned char r, g, b, R, G, B;

    /*
     * Get the HDC handle to the
     * screen (allowing us to create HDCs
     * for accessing bitmap files as well as
     * drawing directly to the screen!)
     */
    c=GetDC(w=GetDesktopWindow());
    /*
     * Create two virtual HDCs for accessing
     * the bitmap files.
     */
    d=A; /* Macro */
    e=A; /* Macro */
    /*
     * Load the two images:
     * The first argument is the image file with
     * the R/G/B channel
     * The second argument is the image file
     * containing the mask defined by the Alpha
     * channel:
     *   Black means = Alpha=0
     *   White means = Alpha>0
     *   (Any other colour means: Alpha>0)
     *
     * Note that "f" is of the type "HBITMAP",
     * not "HDC". We save 4 bytes in the golfed
     * version using HDC instead of HBITMAP and
     * compile the C file with compiler warnings
     * switched off!
     *
     * The second image should have the same size
     * as the first one. However it may be larger
     * than the first one. It must not be smaller!
     */
    SelectObject(d,f=LoadImage(0,n[1],0,0,0,16 /* 16=LR_LOADFROMFILE */));
    SelectObject(e,LoadImage(0,n[2],0,0,0,16));
    /*
     * Get the image information (size)
     */
    GetObject(f,24,s+1);
    /*
     * Search all background colours
     */
    o=LocalAlloc(64 /* Fixed, ZeroInit */,8*s[2]*s[3]);
    for(x=t=Z=s[1]=s[0]=0;x<s[2];x++)
        for(y=0;y<s[3];y++)
            if D
    {
        F; /* Macro */
        for(m=0;m<t && o[m]!=z;m+=2);
        o[m]=z;
        o[m+1]++;
        t+=2*(m>=t);
    }
    /*
     * Search the most common one
     */
    for(x=y=1;x<t;x+=2) if(o[x]>o[y]) y=x;
    z=o[y-1];
    R=z;
    G=z>>8;
    B=z>>16;
    /*
     * Draw the image directly to the screen
     */
    for(x=0;x<s[2];x++)
        for(y=0;y<s[3];y++)
    {
        F; /* Macro */
        /* C and E are macros: */
        SetPixel(c,x,s[3]-y-1,(C(x,y) ||
            (E(r,R) && E(g,G) && E(b,B)))?
            0x232323:0x1B0DFC);
    }
    /*
     * Draw the text over the image
     */
    SelectObject(c,CreateFont(-(s[2]>>2),0,0,0,400,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"Arial"));
    SetBkMode(c,1 /* TRANSPARENT */);
    SetTextColor(c,0xFFFFFF);
    DrawText(c,"-1",2,s,37 /* center, vcenter, singleline */);
    /*
     * Unfortunately DrawText() won't work
     * when not doing this!
     */
    ReleaseDC(w,c);
}
```